# Inferring Gaussian size from cutoff frequency

Tags: image-processing, fft, gaussian

I am trying to interpret the following description of convolution with a Gaussian filter:

> Given a 2D binary image with 1s at selected locations, we obtain a
>   continuous map by convolving a Gaussian filter across all locations.
>   We choose the size of the Gaussian to have a cutoff frequency of K
>   cycles per image.

To start with, I am not sure from this description whether the filtering is processed in the frequency domain or in the spatial domain. On one hand, "convolving a filter across all locations" implies the former; on the other hand, "frequency" and "cycles" imply the latter.

I assume that the filtering is processed in the spatial domain. But still, I am puzzled by the way the size of that Gaussian is chosen. I am aware that there is a relation between the size of a Gaussian (determined by sigma) and cut-off frequency:

```
Fc = 1/(2*pi*sigma)
```

where Fc is the cutoff frequency. However, I am not sure how to interpret "cutoff frequency of 8 cycles per image". Does this mean I could simply replace Fc for the value 8 to infer sigma and determine the size of the Gaussian? Or, perhaps I should first convert cycles per image into cycles perpixel?

Comment: Like you said, it is confusing. Could you give the source of the text you quoted so it is possible to look further into your question?

Comment: Thanks you for reading my question! By now, I managed to have the text clarified (and earned the "tumbleweed" badge :). I will soon edit the answer with an update.